# Facebook keeps moving my tag to another face

Tags: facebook, facebook-tags

I'm trying to tag myself in this picture: https://www.facebook.com/meetjspl/photos/ms.c.eJxFzcsNgDAMA9CNkFMHO91~;MUQK7fXJn5BIFmWYzHlFg2vQCRgH3kSCH9Sortz~_IRZoQ2KN3jshJOSzQfVLaL~_wQfMBMoMevQ~-~-.bps.a.1663337740406745.1073741865.126046920802509/1663337833740069/?type=3&theater

I'm one of the few faces who din't get detected as a face. Im sitting there on the top with my hand covering my mouth, a laptop in front of me, the guy sitting next to me have his hand raised.

Whenever I tag myself in this picture and refresh the page, my tagging gets moved to the face of the guy with his hand raised. I just can't get around that, it will move automatically every time no matter how far I put my tag from his face. It's making me really frustrated. How can I solve that?
[image]